# Correct offset calculation for displaying popup on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to show a popup on mouseover for grid. The questions is, how can I show the popup center positioned from top and left for each grid. Can anybody modify the below code for calculating correct offset(left & top), in below plunker code, it's not showing the result as expected. Thanks for any help.

[PLUNKER URL](https://plnkr.co/edit/9c9RQEWy07KL6Dq28fiV?p=preview)

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("ul.listing li").each(function(i){
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            console.log("index->" +i + "<-index " +"left - "+ offset.left+ "<br/> top - "+offset.top);
                $(this).hover(function() {
                    $(".popupContainer").hide();
                    $(".popupContainer").fadeIn(200).html($(this).html()).css({'left': offset.left/3, 'top': offset.top});
                    $(".popupContainer").hover(function(){
                        $(".popupContainer").show();    
                    }, function(){
                        $(".popupContainer").hide();
                    });
                }, function() {
                    $(".popupContainer").hide();
                });
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why dont u try like this
https://plnkr.co/edit/a9zkLP?p=preview

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul.listing li").each(function(i){
        var pop = $('<div class="popupContainer"></div>').html($(this).html());
        $(this).append(pop);
    })
});
```

css:

```
ul.listing li{
  position: relative;
}

.popupContainer{
    position: absolute;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    top:0;
    left:0;
  }
  ul.listing li:hover .popupContainer{display: block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use elements properties `offsetLeft, offsetTop` and `offsetWidth, offsetHeight`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul.listing li").each(function(i){
        $(this).hover(function() {
            var offsetleft = this.offsetLeft;
            var offsettop = this.offsetTop;
            $(".popupContainer").hide();
            $(".popupContainer").fadeIn(200).html($(this).html()).css({'left': offsetleft - this.offsetWidth/2, 'top': offsettop -this.offsetHeight*1.3});
            $(".popupContainer").hover(function(){
                  $(".popupContainer").show();  
                }, function(){
                  $(".popupContainer").hide();
                });
                }, function() {
                    $(".popupContainer").hide();
                });
        });
});
```

Also add some pixels to align correctly.

Comment: In my case you have same behavior for all items and you can add some additional pixels to 'left' and 'top', and it will have same influence for all items. I've updated code. Do you want that right bottom corner of pop up be in the center of image item?